# How to pass gclid parameter manually in JS to Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website build with one of the most amazing frameworks on the world. Unfortunately it has one downside. It does not allow to use query parameters, for example: www.url.com/page/1 is ok but www.url.com/?page=1 is not ok. When you put this URL it uses browser history  so there is no query parameters left in URL.

I have a campaign in Google Adwords that directs users to this website. Auto tagging is on. I've noticed there are 10k clicks to my website, but Analytics does not report such number for Adwords source.

I discovered that Adwords auto tagging is adding gclid parameter to the destination URL. Than, Analytics knows everything about the campaign because Analytics and Adwords are linked together and i should have pretty analytics data on campaigns and their conversions.

But i don't have it. Since my one of greatest website frameworks removes with its JS code the gclid parameter, Analytics does not notice the gclid and not save the source of the user.

To check if it is really my great website framework issue, i've added utm(umt) parameters to my website and checked source in real time in Analytics. It was not reported as source i provided in parameters but a direct visit.

I would like to be able to analize Adwords performance in Analytics. I can not change unfortunately my framework because it is one of the greatest on the world. But i have noticed that before JS code of the framework is fired i have for a while a URL with the parameter gclid.

Some lines below i have my Google Analytics tracking code. Obviously it tries to get gclid from the URL. But it is too late for him. The gclid parameter is gone when Google Analytics tries to read it.

So my question is: since i have gclid, is there any method of Google Analytics to pass it to him? Like say:

var gclid = getGClidBeforeItsToLate(); // i have it covered

// Awesome framework stuff

HeyGoogleAnalyticsHereYouGoItsYourGclidTakeCare(gclid);

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the "[location](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#location)" field and append the gclid parameter.

```
if(gclid) {
  ga('set', 'location', document.location + '?gclid=' + gclid);
}
ga('send','pageview')
```

You have to use the location field, not the "page" field (which takes the page path), since the latter does not change attribution even if you add parameters t the path.

If you have manually set campaign parameters ("utm parameters") you could set them via the campaignMedium/campaignSource/campaignName fields, but since you cannot get the individual campaign values from the gclid you have to overwrite the location (at which point GA will dismiss what it has gathered from the address bar of the browser and use the value you passed in).

Comment: Brilliant. This is what I am looking for. My situation is different, but the requirement is the same. I have a client that is using utm_source (don't ask) to send campaign information (not the source) to a different tracking platform which is completely breaking the GA user journey when we have autotagging in place, so I need to override the the campaign information without changing the url, and campaignName etc wasn't enough.