# Some Google Analytics 4 conversions reported via Firebase are missing in Google Ads

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, single-page-application, firebase-analytics

Many of the conversions that my Firebase web app reports to my Google Analytics 4 property aren't showing up in Google Ads.

I have a single-page web app that uses the [Firebase Analytics JS API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.analytics) to report custom events for a Google Analytics 4 property, including two events that have been marked as conversions in the Google Analytics "Conversions" page. All of the events reported by the app appear as expected in Google Analytics.

The GA4 property is linked with a Google Ads account that has [auto-tagging](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/1752125?hl=en) enabled. I've imported the conversion events using the Ads site with a Count setting of "Every" (rather than "One"), but less than half of new ad-derived conversions are shown in Ads. For example, Analytics reports 55 occurrences of a conversion event two days ago, but Ads reports only 20 occurrences of the event for the same day.

I've used the [Google Analytics Debugger extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en) to confirm that events contain a `tid` parameter with the GA4 property ID and a `dl` parameter that preserves the URL's `gclid` query parameter (using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38161884/how-to-pass-gclid-parameter-manually-in-js-to-google-analytics)). I've also used BigQuery to view the underlying Analytics events, and I can see that their `page_location` parameters preserve the `gclid` parameter and that they have correct `value` and `currency` parameters (e.g. `0.5` and `"USD"`).

Are there other factors that affect whether GA4 events are correctly displayed in Google Ads? I'm confused by the way that some, but not all, events are showing up in Ads. I had a call with Google Ads support this morning but they aren't trained in diagnosing conversion-reporting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are the conversion events not showing up at all, or just not showing up after a couple of days? If it's the former, it's possible that there is a delay before the conversion reporting makes it to Google Ads and gets reported to the console.

As for inspecting the BigQuery conversion events for the correct tracking data, make sure to use the events_ table rather than the events_intraday tables as the summary tables more accurately reflect the count for events logged that day.

Beyond that it looks like your setup is correct since some conversion events are already being reported, but just in case here is [a link to the Google Ads help center](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/6366292?hl=en) on all the steps required to make sure the Google Analytics 4 property used by Firebase is correctly linked to Google Ads.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it doesn't seem like a delay issue. The BigQuery events_20201116 table contains 55 occurrences of one event and 28 of the other, while Ads shows only 20 and 11 for Nov 16 (or the range Nov 15-17, so it also doesn't look like a difference in how events were attributed to days).

Comment: It's four days later now, and the Ads counts stopped increasing after 24 hours or so. The only other things I can think of trying are relinking the property to Ads and creating a Universal Analytics property in case I'm hitting bugs in GA4.